# Using JSR-303 with custom validation

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc

Dear Spring community,

What I am trying to implement is the following:

- I would like to have a custom validator per controller ([via `@InitBinder`](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?103761-Spring-validation))
- I would like Spring to call `validator.validate()` (so [not this way](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?95765-Valid-Not-working#post320983))
- I would like to use JSR-303 `@Valid` annotation for that
- The bean to be validated (`RegistrationForm`) does not have any per-field JSR-303 annotations
- I don't want to include validation implementation (like [Hibernate](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/)) into classpath; it will be useless as from above statement

I basically follow the steps mentioned [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?88755-Commons-Validator-to-Spring-MVC-3-Validation#post314296):

- I add `javax.validation.validation-api:validation-api` as my dependency
- I use `<mvc:annotation-driven />`
- I mark my model with `@Valid`: 
  `public String onRegistrationFormSubmitted(@ModelAttribute("registrationForm") @Valid RegistrationForm registrationForm, BindingResult result) ...`

So what happens, is that validation API tries to locate any implementation and fails:

```
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:264)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:183)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
```

The way out is to define a `validator` property for `AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser`:

```
<bean name="validator" class="org.company.module.RegistrationFormValidator" />

<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator" />
```

but this approach means that the validator will be set to all controllers by `ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer.initBinder()`.

I understand that I am trying to use the framework in a special way, but what the community will say, if there is a special meaning for `validator` property which tells that validator does not need to be resolved, e.g.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven validator="manual" />
```

with special treatment:

```
--- AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java.orig      2011-06-30 14:33:10.287577300 +0200
+++ AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java   2011-06-30 14:34:27.897449000 +0200
@@ -152,6 +152,10 @@

        private RuntimeBeanReference getValidator(Element element, Object source, ParserContext parserContext) {
                if (element.hasAttribute("validator")) {
+                       if ("manual".equals(element.getAttribute("validator"))) {
+                               return null;
+                       }
+
                        return new RuntimeBeanReference(element.getAttribute("validator"));
                }
                else if (jsr303Present) {
```

Any feedback is welcomed.

P.S. Repost from [Spring Forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?111456-Partially-using-JSR-303-for-validation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is also a repost of my answer/workaround on the [above mentioned forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?111456-Partially-using-JSR-303-for-validation&p=409120#post409120). Anyway I think it might help having it here as well.

The only workaround I found was to implement my own `@Valid` annotation, once Spring (at least in 3.1.1.RELEASE code base) only checks the method argument annotation's simple name (please look into the `org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor` class below). This way, I don't need to add `javax.validation.validation-api:validation-api` to my project's dependencies and I stop getting the infamous `javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider`.

```
/**
 * Validate the model attribute if applicable.
 * <p>The default implementation checks for {@code @javax.validation.Valid}.
 * @param binder the DataBinder to be used
 * @param parameter the method parameter
 */
protected void validateIfApplicable(WebDataBinder binder, MethodParameter parameter) {
    Annotation[] annotations = parameter.getParameterAnnotations();
    for (Annotation annot : annotations) {
        if (annot.annotationType().getSimpleName().startsWith("Valid")) {
            Object hints = AnnotationUtils.getValue(annot);
            binder.validate(hints instanceof Object[] ? (Object[]) hints : new Object[] {hints});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, good solution. Indeed, if `validation-api` is not in classpath, then `<mvc:annotation-driven />` will not try to initialize the implementation via the factory. Hence the binder-specific validator will be used. Do you set the validator through controller's `initBinder()`?

Comment: Thanks! And yes, using initBinder() the way it's suggested in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't want to include Hibernate Validator?
Ever JSR specification have some implementations, you can not work with the specification without any implementation (or provider).

Can you imagine working with JDBC without any JDBC driver? Working with JPA without a provider? Working with Servlets without any container?

It's just the same, Hibernate Validator is the reference implementation of JSR-303, I'm not aware of any other implementation, but if you don't like Hibernate Validator, just go for another implementation.

Comment: I don't want to include the Hibernate validator because it too heavy-weight. Spring Framework offers another level abstraction (`org.springframework.validation.Validator`) which is not bound to e.g. JSR-303. I know how to validate my bean and I would like Spring to call this validation function. The bean `RegistrationForm` does not have any further JSR-303 annotations, so it is useless for real implementation.

Comment: And one more remark, concerning API without implementation. There is a difference: use of API and use of annotations. Interfaces are "useless" without implementation, but annotations are not. Real world example: JAXB annotations can be used without JAXB runtime by Jackson. So `@Valid` annotation can be used to signal Spring to force validation; the binder will decide, *what particular implementation to use*.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> I add javax.validation.validation-api:validation-api as my dependency ...
>
> Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider

You will also need an implemenation of that api. For example Hibernate Validator, it is the default implmentation. (has nothing to do with the ORM Hibernate)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. As I mentioned, I know about Hibernate validation implementation. I want a solution without it.

Comment: @dma_k, I see, but why do you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I don't want to re-invent the wheel (= validation engine). The bean to be validated (`RegistrationForm`) does not have any per-field JSR-303 annotations thus real implementation is useless. I have updated the question a bit to have this statement clear (see top bullet points). As I mentioned I am aware about "direct" use of JSR-303. The patch I've provided (I believe) adds more flexibility to the framework. What do you think?